# Initialization of the Network Simplex Method

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, network, network-flow, simplex-method

I am studying Chapter 7 (Network Flow Problems) of the book [*Introduction to Linear Optimization* by Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis](http://athenasc.com/linoptbook.html). On page 286 the authors briefly describe a way to deal with the initialization of the minimum cost network flow problem:

> In the case where finding an initial basic feasible solution is difficult, we may need to form and solve an auxiliary problem. For example, for each pair of source and sink nodes, we may introduce an auxiliary arc; finding a basic feasible solution in the presence of these arcs is straightforward. Furthermore, if the unit costs $c_{ij}$ of the auxiliary arcs are chosen large enough, solving the auxiliary problem is equivalent to solving the original problem.

A minimum cost network flow problem takes the following form. A network is a directed graph $G=(\mathcal{N},\mathcal{A})$ together with some additional numerical information, including $b_i$ representing the supply to (if $b_i>0$) or demand of (if $b_i<0$) each node $i\in\mathcal{N}$, nonnegative numbers $u_{ij}$ representing the capacity of each arc $(i,j)\in\mathcal{A}$, and numbers $c_{ij}$ representing the cost per unit flow along arc $(i,j)$. The minimum cost network flow problem is
$$
\begin{align*}
\min&\quad\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{A}}c_{ij}f_{ij} \\
\text{s.t.}&\quad b_i+\sum_{\{j\in\mathcal{N}:(j,i)\in\mathcal{A}\}}f_{ji}=\sum_{\{j\in\mathcal{N}:(i,j)\in\mathcal{A}\}}f_{ij},\quad\forall\,i\in\mathcal{N} \\
&\quad 0\le f_{ij}\le u_{ij},\quad\forall\,(i,j)\in\mathcal{A},
\end{align*}
$$
where the decision variable $f_{ij}$ represents the amount of flow along arc $(i,j)$.

**My question:** Why do the authors say it is straightforward to find a basic feasible solution in the presence of these arcs?

In my understanding, this method resembles the big-$M$ method for general linear programming: we introduce auxiliary variables $y$ in the constraints and add $M\sum_jy_j$ to the objective, and then the initial basic variables are $y$. However, I don't see how the same trick extends to the network flow problem. Intuitively, I need to pick some nonzero auxiliary arcs and also some arcs between nodes with zero supply and demand, and these arcs need to form a tree. Is there a general procedure to do this?

Comment: To build a spanning tree, you can start with all the auxiliary arcs in it and keep adding arcs that don't form a cycle until you have a spanning tree. This is essentially what Kruskal's algorithm does, except that it starts with an empty set and sorts the arcs in increasing order of cost/weight before it starts adding them to the tree.

Comment: But Kruskal's algorithm only applies to undirected graphs. The solution it gives must be a basic solution, but not necessarily feasible. @VHarisop

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why the solution would not be feasible. After all, it will preserve all flow conservation constraints (the flow will be 0 everywhere except on the auxiliary arcs), and if I remember correctly the direction of the edges is not important. Would you mind adding more information in your original post, since the book is not free available?

Comment: I have added a formulation of the min cost network flow problem.  The main issue is that the problem deals with a directed graph, whereas minimum spanning tree is (generally) a concept for undirected graph. @VHarisop

Answer (score 1):

This is best explained with an example, consider this min-flow network where $b_i$ are the supply (positive) and demands (negative) of each node:

[image]

We can add an artificial node $6$ and artificial arcs connecting all nodes in the graph to the artificial node $6$ like so:

[image]

The numbers near the arcs in the above graph are the amount of units being sent through each arc to each node, satisfying all the demands and supply of all nodes. However, like the Big-M method, the cost of sending a unit through each one of these arcs is $M$, so the initial solution $z$ will be $z=18M$. Since $M$ is an arbitrarily large number, this initial solution will be really bad for the model, but it will be a baseplate/platform for the Network Simplex algorithm to use as it will generate better solutions from the original arcs from the original graph.

However, in the process of the Network Simplex should it terminate with a final solution that has non-zero flows on any of the artificial arcs, then the original min-flow problem is considered infeasible.